# Meaning of this type of integral (Perhaps Riemann-Stiltjes?)

Tags: integration

I have come across the integral 
$$
\int_0^{k_{fm}}\frac{A\hbar}{2m(2\pi)^2}k^2d^2k
$$
(from physics) 
which is supposed to equal: 
$$
\frac{A\hbar}{16m\pi}k_{fm}^4
$$
My first thought is that this is a Riemann-Stiltjes integral and that it should be computed by:
$$
\int_0^{k_{fm}}\frac{A\hbar}{2m(2\pi)^2}k^2d^2k=\int_0^{k_{fm}}\frac{A\hbar}{2m(2\pi)^2}k^2 (2k) dk=\int_0^{k_{fm}}\frac{A\hbar}{m(2\pi)^2}k^3dk=\frac{A\hbar}{16m\pi^2}k_{fm}^4
$$

But this is off, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All I can think of is that it might be an integral over an area. But I have no real context.

Comment: No, not really, thats all information I have. It is over a line.

Comment: Well then I'm stumped.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an integral over density of modes in reciprocal space $k = (k_x, k_y)$ for the 2D case. The $k^2$ would stem from the approximation of discrete points to a continuous function and the $(2\pi)^2$ from the reciprocal space area. Adding the angular integral yields correct solution :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+2+pi+A+h+%2F+(2+m+(2+pi)%5E2)+s%5E3+from+s+%3D+0+to+s+%3D+k

Comment: don't forget to integrate over the angle! :()